# add push notifications to a closed binary .apk android app

Tags: android, push-notification, android-manifest

I hired a developer to create an android app. The work had been done. I received myapp.apk. It's working properly.

Now, I want to to add push notifications function to the app. The developer is not available again. I did not received any source code. I just received the myapp.apk.

I found that I can extract myapp.apk. After extraction, there is a file called AndroidManifest.xml and many other files and folder.

Can I add push notifications by modifying AndroidManifest.xml file? If yes, what are further steps needed? If no, what are all possible methods to add the push notifications to myapp.apk?

Comment: There is a lot more work to be done, depending on what backend are you using for push notifications, and to handle the response to those push notifications you may need BroadcastRecievers.

Comment: @ AseedUsmani Thanks so much for your comment. The app is packaged as .apk, can we still implement what is called BroadcastRecievers?

Comment: @Basem Have a look at the answers to this question on Quara: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-decompile-an-android-app-and-edit-its-java-source-and-again-recompile-it  and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Answer (score 1):

It is much more complicated than just modifying the AndroidManifest file.

Typically, there would be three things to do:

1. Setup code in your app to receive a Push Notification.  This is usually done in a BroadcastReceiver.
2. Register with some type of service such as Google Cloud Messaging, Firebase Cloud Messaging, or Parse.
3. You will likely need some type of code on a server that determines when to send your Push Notifications and what the content will be.

Doing it through Google Cloud Messaging / Firebase Cloud Messaging is the more common and robust approach.  [You can find information about it here.](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

You could also do it through a service called Parse.  I have used Parse in the past and it was much easier to setup than Google Cloud Messaging but is more basic.  [You can find information about Parse here.](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications)

If you are looking for the easiest possible way to send basic Push Notifications, I would go with Parse.  There is still a good amount of setup to do, but it is the easiest option that I am aware of.

Comment: Would note that Parse is closing down their managed service very soon.

Comment: @Stephen-Ruda Thanks for your answer. Can we say that part 2 and 3 of above answer are easier to implement compared to part 1?
Another question; the app is packaged as .apk, can we still setup code in the app to receive a Push Notification?